# How do i set up midi2audio on Windows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, midi

I'm trying to use the midi2sound python library, but i cant get it working!
it keeps spitting out the error `FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified` whenever i try to convert a midi file to sound.

I don't really think there's anything that the script im using it in will provide, but here's a snippet that would cause this error for me:

```
from midi2audio import FluidSynth

fs = FluidSynth("Musical_Box.sf2")

fs.midi_to_audio("input.mid", "output.wav")
```

And yes, the midi file and soundfont file are in the same directory that the script is running in, so i honestly have no clue about what to do.

I've tried installing FluidSynth under (User)/.fluidsynth/ and putting a soundfont there too.
And yes, the midi file and soundfont file are in the same directory that the script is running in, so i honestly have no clue about what to do.

My preferred results from this would be to successfully convert a midi file to a wave file, or if not possible to at least find an alternative library

Comment: I would look into this GitHub issue thread about this same problem https://github.com/bzamecnik/midi2audio/issues/4

Comment: @CootMoon I have looked there, but i didn't see any way to resolve the issue

Comment: dang, I wish you the best of luck.

Comment: In any case, that seems like an obvious bug to me, so it's something for the bugtracker, not for SO. That said, typical error causes are that people are not aware how a  working directory for a process works, so: Does it work with absolute paths? Can you use the same path to open and read the file?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Nope, absolute paths fail in the same way. And I would've opened an issue if one didn't exist already.

Since there may be no fix for this, I may move on to trying to find an alternative to midi2audio

Comment: Or you could earn some internet fame by fixing it. ;)

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Maybe :P

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so, if you're on windows, you need to install [FluidSynth](https://github.com/FluidSynth/fluidsynth/releases), and put the path to it's executable in your PATH environment variable.

You can do this by searching for "Edit the system environment variables" and navigating to the environment variables area from there.

Double click on "Path" and inside that window click "New". Write the path to wherever the executable is stored, click "OK" until all windows are closed, and then restart your console or whatever IDE you're using so the changes can take effect.